# Flutter IntelliJ Errors without Line Numbers

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

Recently errors in build methods started being quite cryptic in Flutter. I'm running in Debug mode. The IDE does not break at the exception and there is no line number in the exception report.

What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing instead?

Below are screenshots that may help:

The error log that I see:

[image: the error]

The setting that should catch Dart exceptions:

[image: the setting]

The device screen:

[image: the device screen]

EDIT: After a hot reload, I get the stack trace that I expected:

[image: the stack trace after hot reload]

I guess I hit a bug? The Flutter version as requested:

> Flutter 1.2.2-pre.21 • channel master •
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 035e0765cc
>   (7 days ago) • 2019-02-16 01:48:28 -0500 Engine • revision f37b09a11b
>   Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 c92d5ca288)

Switched back to beta and the same problem persists.

> Flutter 1.1.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>   Framework • revision 985ccb6d14 (7 weeks ago) • 2019-01-08 13:45:55
>   -0800 Engine • revision 7112b72cc2 Tools • Dart 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)

I get the same thing (one line error with no stacktrace) with `flutter run lib\main.dart`.

Comment: whats the full stacktrace? tried to run `flutter run lib/xxxx.dart` from the terminal window?

Comment: Yeah the thing is I don't get the stacktrace at all!... I get it after a hot reload, though. Probably I hit a bug... I'll update the q.

Comment: tried to tun `flutter run lib/xxxx.dart` command? also what is the output of `flutter --version` command?

Comment: Why do you want me to try `flutter run`? I'm not trying to solve my app's problems, I'm trying to understand this weird behavior. I edited the q for the flutter version.

Comment: I should probably get back to beta. master channel may be dangerous:)

Comment: this "weird behavior" may be caused by your android studio, by weird filtering etc, thats why `flutter run` gives you for sure the best output

Comment: I don't have any filters in my output. I use IntelliJ. I just switched back to channel beta and still in the first run in debug mode results in this weird behavior. I just ran it with `flutter run` and I got the same short error message with no stacktrace at the first exception... Like I said, I get the full error output after the first hot reload. Weird.

Comment: I do have the same error. 'int' is not a subtype of 'double' but I'm not sure which line causes this. How did you resolve it?